# Does Linux have any symlinks by default?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, fhs

I have written [a program](https://github.com/CiscoCloud/distributive) that performs health checks on servers. One of its functions is that it can check whether or not a symlink exists. I am currently in the process of writing unit tests (for use with Travis CI), and I'm wondering if there are any symlinks that I can depend on being there on any Linux system.

For example, I currently unit test with `/bin/sh`, which is usually a symlink to something like `/bin/bash`.

Does Linux have a set of symlinks that are there by default?

Comment: Why not just make a symlink as part of the setup for the unit test? `/bin/sh` does not have to be a symlink.

Comment: Linux is a kernel. Nothing else. The operating systems using Linux as kernel differ a lot.

Comment: There are a number standard symlinks in `/proc`, but I don't think there is any "universal" symlink in a real filesystem.  The various distributions are quite different from one another, even if you consider, say, only desktop-class systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because there is no standard Linux distribution. Linux is just a kernel, and doesn't specify anything about user-space, including file layout. If you want to narrow this down to a subset of Linux distributions, you might be able to find something (with, as you note, `/bin/sh` as a good candidate)

However, the kernel itself does have some special fileystems, notably /proc and /sys, which are part of the kernel directly, and which contain symlinks. Therefore, for example:

```
$ file /proc/$$/exe
/proc/7622/exe: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/bash'
```

However, I'm not sure I'd rely on this for your tests, because a) proc might actually not be available within every testing system, and b) since it's not a real filesystem, it seems a little dodgy. Why not just create your own symlink as part of your test?